# Make a Record in python using 3 list

Tags: python, list, records

So i have three list i generated from a excel file, i need to combine them in to a record if possible.  The list 1 is Names, 2,3 are numbers. these list have over a thousand entry's. Thanks for you help .

```
rb= Record()
rb.attribute1= ReRegister
rb.attribute2= ReName
rb.attribute3= ReNumbers
```

Comment: Everything i read about it does not make alot of sense to me

Comment: I tryed something like this, where the Rex is my list but yea no work

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you have 3 lists of same length and that each element in each list is elated with each other by the same index, you could do:

```
class Record:
    def __init__(self, name, register,numbers):
        self.name = name
        self.register = register
        self.numbers = numbers

zipped_lists = zip(list1,list2,list3)
records = [Record(*data) for data in zipped_lists]
```

Of course, it will only work if you have a class definition like that.